# azure api management error 500

Tags: api, azure

I configured an Api using API management service in Azure, all the endpoints are working fine, I defined some rules into the inbound policies, the last one is a set backend service rule. the objective of this rule is redirect the request to a diferent endpoint based on certain conditions. The problem is as follow: If i test the api endpoint inside the Azure,using the the Test option provided by API managemen service all the proceess works fine, i can see into the trace and check how the Api Management service recieve the request, check the conditions definen into the inbound policy and finally change the backend url to the right endpoint. If test outside the Azure, for example using postman, the API management service response an 500 error, the description of the error is: **Expression value is invalid. Value is not a valid absolute URL. () Section : (inbound) Source : (set-backend-service)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and the solution. The problem was generated in the policies configuration. For some reason the base tag in the backend policy was deleted. Putting back the base tag all the endpoints works fine.